# What does the alcohol functional group (specifically oxygen) have to do that causes an alcohol to have a lower energy content than an alkane?

Tags: energy, alcohols, fuel

My textbook said that the carbon is "partially oxidised" (don't really know what that means) and I just wanted to confirm.

Comment: Search for what oxidized means and what partially means.

Answer (score 2):

Energy released from organic compounds by burning is based on oxidation,  breaking $\ce{O2}$, $\ce{C-C}$ and $\ce{C-H}$ chemical bounds and creation of $\ce{O-H}$ and $\ce{C=O}$ bounds. The latter are stronger than the former, need more energy to be broken, but OTOH more energy is released when they are created. This energy difference of chemical bounds leads to releasing energy.

If a substance already has some oxygen in its molecule, part of this bond rearranging is already done, so we can say the substance is already partially oxidized. The energy released by burning rearranges just the rest of the bonds and is lower.

Another factor affecting the specific burning enthalpy $\Delta H$ in $\pu{MJ/kg}$ is the relatively higher mass of oxygen atoms, compared to hydrogen and carbon atoms. Oxygen acts here like a "dead weight".

An extreme example are explosives, that are very rich in oxygen and need not an external oxygen to be burned. E.g. TNT releases about 10 times less energy than burning the same mass of coal. ( But much faster, of course ).